# Laravel passport with custom login controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

As mention in [laravel-passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) the login controller is made from `php artisan make:auth` and in our router `web.php` would have `Auth::routes();`

Simple code in our `client-site`

```
Route::get('/redirect', function () {

    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://client-site/callback-responses-url',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => ''
    ]);

    return redirect('http://server-site/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});
```

If the user is not log in the `http://server-site/oauth/authorize?'.$query` would be redirect to `http://server-site/login`

In any case of it i would like to redirect the login controller to my custom login controller. Then after i done check the use if is true would be show view about `authorization request agreement`

Simply i have tried to check `oauth/authorize` and i didnt find any function or controller handle that link. And if given any chance again. I would to know, more about the `laravel-passport` how the oauth work, and so do i could make the `custom authorization view` too after the user has login

Any help would be so helpful thank you (:

Comment: you have to use `laravel/passport` package to achieve this

Comment: what do you mean ? @AdnanMumtaz

Comment: please follow this guide it is pretty easy https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: im so appreciate for your mention, but i have followed the tutorial@AdnanMumtaz

Comment: Was you able to find a solution? I am trying to do exactly the same! I need to customize the autorization view with Client Logo, description etc.

Comment: @Sisir in my answer thats all i know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i do a big search in laravel passport, i got the solution how to customize the laravel passport.

in your `app\Exception\Handler.php` there is a code

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    //return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    return redirect()->guest(route('accountLogin')); // change this part to your login router
}
```

then in your `login controller` which is handler the success login add this code

```
if(session("url")["intended"] != null){
    $redirect = session("url")["intended"];
}else{
    $redirect = "/home";
}

return Redirect($redirect);
```

That codes are for redirect back to the client page. Surely if you know a bit more about the `AuthenticatesUsers` in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth` how they works, you could build your own beautiful code.

The last step i found is here : [RouteRegistarar](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/3.0/src/RouteRegistrar.php) this is for how the route authorization is crossed.

Untill now, i am not yet customize my authorization page. Currently i was doing a beautiful `third party` code, so client could be easy to use it.

Thats all i know about the laravel passport to customize the login page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `personal access token` method

in there you write your custom authentication method and when a pass that custom auth, u generate an access token for the user

i.e public function myCustomLoginMethod(Request $req) {

```
  // your custom authentication here
 $user = User::where("email",$req->email);

 //test for password and like so
 if (! Hash::check($req->password, $user->password)) {
      // wrong password
      return response('Unauthorize', 401);
  }

 if ( $user->is_admin ) {
    //create a token for the user
    $token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
 }else {
    //handle else
 }

  return token
```

}